# How to format a text in html

Tags: html, grails

I have a .gsp, that displays a number in the page. The problem is, i receive that number (from the server) with decimals, even if the decimal is 0. I would like to "if the last character in this string is 0, erase from the dot till the end"

Any idea? if possible, without touching the server side.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off treating numbers as numbers (parsing them if needed), and then using format tags that come bundled with Grails. In this case [g:formatNumber](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html) would be appropriate.

Comment: Specifically, <g:formatNumber number="${your.number}" type="number" minIntegerDigits="0" />

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript/jQuery but not with CSS.

Comment: The css tag is there because of a question I was about to ask before, but finally didn't, it remained there when i were going to ask this one.

Answer (score 0):

on your .gsp page do a **g:if** test at the place where you display the number. Check if the last character is 0, if it is, do a **toString()** on the number, **split** by the '.' and show the the string at 0th index.